# Conda install packages from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, installation, pip, jupyter, conda

I have used `!{sys.executable} -m pip install` to install packages i want to use in my jupyter notebooks.

Now i also want to install some packaged by conda and use in the same notebooks.

[image: This is the command i run and the error message]

They ask us to create a separate conda environment. I am confused about this.

Do we need to create a new conda enviroment everytime we need new packages?
What is the correct way to install and access conda packages on jupyter python notebook?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't in principle install **from** the jupyter notebook but from the terminal/cmd.

You can create an enviroment `>conda create --name myenv`
And activate it: `>conda activate myenv`

now everything you install will be restricted to myenv. for example `conda install numpy`

To use the packages in myenv in jupyter simply open jupyter with your enviroment active:

```
>conda activate myenv
>jupyter notebook
```

Note that you have to install jupyter in your enviroment too: `conda install jupyter`

Comment: In this case, I will need to reinstall the packages that i need in the conda environment. Can i use pip install to install in the conda environment?

Comment: Yes, but generally all packages you can install with pip can be installed with `conda install` too. I would recomend trying `conda install` before resorting to pip